# Divs overlap while using absolute position in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have the div with id `our_team` below the div with id `services`. The former is getting overlapped with the latter while using `absolute` positioning.

The `services` div flips to list some information about it while hovering by using `absolute` positioning.
The `our_team` div has just some `header` & `paragraph` tags but it is overlapping on first div.

If I remove the absolute positioning, the divs are arranged properly but it's flipping with empty white blocks.
[image: Before Flipping]

So, when I add the `absolute` positioning, the divs are overlapped.
[image: overlapping divs]

HTML & CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/dasasathyan/8rjoqdnt/

Comment: Any chance you could provide an image of what you want. I'm a bit confused at what the results should be. And don't use first div second div to describe. You have about 20 divs in the html. Be specific about which elements (by name) you want to be positioned. Also all of your flip cards share the same classes making it difficult for you to target one card to get it out of the way.

Comment: Additionally what are `.services_heading` and `.services_card` for in the css. Those elements don't exist in the html.

Comment: @Justin sorry for the disambiguity. I have edited the question now.

Comment: The quickest way would be to apply a position to the `our-team` . `#our_team {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 40px;
}` I don't think it's the best way to do this however.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time getting it done the way it was written. If it's not too much of a re-write for you and using flex is ok this may work
HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="services">
      <div id="row1_cards">
        <div id="left_card">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <h3> Some Heading 1 that flips of first DIV </h3>
            <h6>1st Heading Description</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <ul class="services_list">
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right_card">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <h3> Some Heading 2 that flips of first DIV </h3>
            <p>2nd Heading Description</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <ul class="services_list">
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
              <li>Some List Item</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="our_team">
      <div id="row2_team">
        <div class="col">
          <p>2nd Div that should come under the 1st Div</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>2nd Div that should come under the 1st Div</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#main_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 750px;
  height: auto;
}
#row1_cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 50px;
}
#row2_team {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 50px;
}
#left_card {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
#right_card {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.flip-card-front {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 45px 20px 0 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0068a5 0%, #003367 100%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-card-back {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#left_card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#right_card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to have defined heights for elements, absolute position will cause issues (as you've shown). An alternative would be to use a different technique to position and flip your cards using flex.

You can transition using z-index values (ie. `transition: z-index, transform 0.6s;`) and moving the elements with something like this:

```
.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(100%, 0);
}
```

This would allow you to skip using `position: absolute` altogether. I made some adjustments to the fiddle to show you, and some of the styling can be changed to suit your needs (like having all cards the same height as the largest element, for example).

Fiddle with changes: https://jsfiddle.net/pie9/ftr6w9sj/

[MDN docs for translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()) [MDN docs for z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)